# Linux listing files between two date without touch command

Tags: shell, files, ls, date

I need a command which will list the files between given date and time (YYYYMMDDHHMMSS - format) in to a text file.

I don want to use touch command as its creating permission issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use `touch` if you have a recent version of a recent version of GNU `find` ( >=  v4.3.3 ). With that you can do:

```
find /media/WD/backup/osool/olddata/ -newermt 20120101T1200 -not -newermt 20130101T1400
```

Please note the `T` between day and hours.

If you want to retry using `touch` to create reference files for `-newer`: you can put those anywhere where you can write ( `/var/tmp`?), as long as you specify the full path to `-newer`. So you might still find a place where you have permissions.

Comment: Thanks Anthon , giving path to -newer: worked with touch!

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload age
ls -ldrt -- **/*(e{age 2013/03/06:13:20:00 2013/05/18:11:00:00})
```

See:

```
info -f zsh --index-search=age
```

for details.

(note that it will be a lot less efficient than Anthon's GNU find solution as it will parse those dates, do 2 `lstat`s for every file and sort the list of files (you can avoid that last part by adding `oN` to the list of globbing qualifiers; use `D` to include dotfiles)).